# Using php I need to have 2 different connections to the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection

I have a need to copy some rows from a database to a different database.  I am experiencing difficulty.  I have found several methods except none of the seem to work.  The php version I am using is 5.4.

Both connections are in the same server, however everything else is different

This is the php code that I have found and it doesnt seem to work at all, I am unable to select from the first database

```
// Create connection
$wpdb = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($wpdb->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $wpdb->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected local successfully\n";

//$starttime = date("h:i:sa");

$mydb = mysql_connect('localhost','dbname','dbpassword', true);

// Check connection
if ($mydb->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mydb->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected to Integrity successfully\n";

mysql_select_db($database, $wpdb);
mysql_select_db('wordpress_0', $mydb);
```

Comment: you dont need 2 connections for what you state yo want to do. it can probably be done wit ha single insert select querry https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: First off don't use `mysql_` as it's been removed from PHP7, not to mention it does not return a connection object (it returns a resource handle), so this won't work `$wpdb->connect_error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with PDO.that provide a common interface to talk with many different databases.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 
'password');
```

Comment: Hi Mohan,  This makes the most sense to me and seems to work just like I want it to.

Comment: Is there a simple way to make an insert statement from a assoc array?

Answer (score 0):

I refuse to offer support for `mysql_` syntax, so I'll offer the upgraded version.

Almost entirely copied from the php manual... http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Code:

```
/* attempt and check connection including first database selection "test" */
if (!$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test")) {
    // never show the actual error to the public
    echo "<div>Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error , "</div>";
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if (!$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    // never show the actual error to the public
    echo "<div>Syntax Error: " , $conn->error , "</div>";
} else {    
    echo "<div>Default database is: " , $result->fetch_row()[0] , "</div>";
    $result->close();
}

/* change db to "mysql" db */
$mysqli->select_db("mysql");

/* return name of current default database */
if (!$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    // never show the actual error to the public
    echo "<div>Syntax Error: " , $conn->error , "</div>";
} else {    
    echo "<div>Default database is: " , $result->fetch_row()[0] , "</div>";
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Output:

```
Default database is: test
Default database is: mysql
```